# Where can I find the available Canvas events that I can subscribe to?

Tags: canvas

There is an example in [Subscribing to Parent Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_subscribe_code_example.htm) that shows I can subscribe to onscroll events from the parent window using `'canvas.scroll'`.

```
//Subscribe to the parent window onscroll event.
Sfdc.canvas(function() {
    sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
    // Capture the onScrolling event of the parent window
    Sfdc.canvas.client.subscribe(sr.client,
        {name : 'canvas.scroll', onData : function (event) {
            console.log("Parent's contentHeight; " + event.heights.contentHeight);
            console.log("Parent's pageHeight; " + event.heights.pageHeight);
            console.log("Parent's scrollTop; " + event.heights.scrollTop);
            console.log("Parent's contentWidth; " + event.widths.contentWidth);
            console.log("Parent's pageWidth; " + event.widths.pageWidth);
            console.log("Parent's scrollLeft; " + event.widths.scrollLeft);
        }}
    );
});
```

What other events are there to subscribe to? I can't find any documentation beyond 'canvas.scroll'.

In particular, I'd like to know when the window is resized so I can manually resize the iframe using `Sfdc.canvas.client.resize`.

---

So I found this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_resizing.htm?search_text=canvas.scroll):

> Currently, canvas.scroll (of the parent) is the only supported parent event in the canvas namespace.

Which I thought was the answer. But then I also found `'canvas.orientation'` in 
[Handling Orientation Changes in Your Canvas App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_orientation_code_example.htm?search_text=canvas.scroll) (Added [Summer '14](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_forcecom_canvas_orientation_event.htm)).

Comment: I was really hoping this was a Q&A style question.

Comment: @sfdcfox It certainly started that way. I'd like to know what events I can subscribe to. I then found some docs that made it appear there was only a single event. Then I found some more that suggested there was at least another one. So I'm still uncertain about what events are available :/

Comment: @sfdcfox Do you think I should split the findings from the documentation out into an answer? They aren't really a complete answer due to the contradiction.

Comment: I say give it like 24-48 hours and see if someone comes up with something. Being unanswered should make it more visible. I can also contribute to a bounty if you want. I believe I might have the rep to spare ;-)

Comment: [An egg from the docs team said they were going to look into it](https://twitter.com/DocsPdreyfus/status/746169098946682882). Will hopefully get an official answer soon. Save your rep for a rainy day :)